# continuing an iterator with a different iterator without affecting the first one

Tags: python, iterator

I am creating an iterator using the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function and iterating several steps using the iterator.

I then want to continue iterating from the same place with a different iterator without affecting the original iterator object.

example:

consider the iterator object `org_iter`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> org_iter = iter(a)
```

iterating over it:

```
>>> next(org_iter)
1
```

using `iter` again gives the same instance of the iterator instead of a different one from the same location:

```
>>> new_iter = iter(org_iter)
>>> next(new_iter)  # continuing 
2
>>> next(org_iter)  # "org_iter is new_iter"
3
```

EDIT because of comment: using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) doesn't work either:

```
>>> new_iter = itertools.tee(org_iter)
>>> next(new_iter[0])
2
>>> next(org_iter)
3
```

---

the same functionality could be achieved by using different variables to hold the index numbers and `+=1`ing them.

or with the `enumerate` function and nested `for` loops.

but i am specifically asking about using an iterator object directly.

Comment: You are using [tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) incorrectly. You would do `it1, it2=itertools.tee(iter(a))` and it then works as you expect. You cannot use the original iterator once you have used `tee`.

Comment: this doesn't allow me to continue from the same place as the original iterator, i will have to create both of them at the beginning and iterate over both of them and this is not my question. i am creating iterators dynamically i can't know how many i will need.

Comment: Again: It works as expected so long as you do not use the original. Try: `oi=iter(a)` couple of nexts then do `i1,i2=itertools.tee(iter(oi))` and don't use `oi` at that point. `i1` and `i2` are now where `oi` was and can be used independently from there.

Comment: If it is not clear, you can also reuse the original name: `oi,new_i=itertools.tee(iter(oi))` so it is functionally the same as keeping the original.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of without using any external modules would be by doing:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> org_iter = iter(a)
>>> id(org_iter)
58713584
>>> new_iter = iter(list(org_iter))
>>> id(new_iter)
58299600
```

Comment: this destroys the `org_iter`, doing  `next(org_iter)` gives me `StopIteration` exception.